# Got stuck at deserializing a JSON web response

Tags: c#, json

I have some problems deserializing the following JSON string. On all of my other responses it works really good but not for this one. I tried so many different things and I checked the Stream class about 100 times. I also have used a generated class from json2csharp but all my deserialized Data is NULL.

My code to get the response:

```
    public Stream getStream(string userID)
    {
        var request = GetRequest("streams/{channelID}", Method.GET);
        request.AddUrlSegment("channelID", userID);
        var response = restClient.Execute<Stream>(request);
        return response.Data;
    }
```

response.Content shows me as example something like that:

```
{
"stream":
    {
    "_id":25649270464,
    "game":"test",
    "broadcast_platform":"other",
    "community_id":"xxxxxxxxx",
    "community_ids":["xxxxxx"],
    "viewers":2421,
    "video_height":1080,
    "average_fps":61.7876424715,
    "delay":0,
    "created_at":"2017-07-02T10:01:28Z",
    "is_playlist":false,
    "stream_type":"live",
    "preview":
        {
        "small":"https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_lostaiming-80x45.jpg",
        "medium":"https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_lostaiming-320x180.jpg",
        "large":"https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_lostaiming-640x360.jpg",
        "template":"https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_lostaiming-{width}x{height}.jpg"
        },
    "channel":
        {
        "mature":false,
        "status":"Test"
        ,"broadcaster_language":"de",
        "display_name":"LOSTAIMING",
        "game":"test",
        "language":"en",
        "_id":44281267,
        "name":"lostaiming",
        "created_at":"2013-06-02T16:42:19.329009Z",
        "updated_at":"2017-07-02T13:05:11.555285Z",
        "partner":true,
        "logo":"https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/lostaiming-profile_image-e9d7ea0893748d6a-300x300.png",
        "video_banner":"https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/cc34c6b909a435ae-channel_offline_image-1920x1080.png",
        "profile_banner":"https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/c187e8871c0f6a2b-profile_banner-480.png",
        "profile_banner_background_color":"",
        "url":"https://www.twitch.tv/lostaiming",
        "views":2292173,
        "followers":55672,
        "broadcaster_type":"",
        "description":"Blubb"
        }
    }
}
```

And my Stream class looks like this:

```
    class Stream
{
    [JsonProperty("stream")]
    public SubStream stream { get; set; }
}
class SubStream
{      
    [JsonProperty("_id")]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("game")]
    public string Game { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("broadcast_platform")]
    public string BroadcastPlatform { get; set; }       
    [JsonProperty("community_id")]
    public string CommunityID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("community_ids")]
    public List<object> CommunityIDS { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("viewers")]
    public long Viewers { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("video_height")]
    public long VideoHeigt { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("average_fps")]
    public double AverageFps { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("delay")]
    public long Delay { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("createt_at")]
    public DateTime CreatetAt { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("is_playlist")]
    public bool IsPlaylist { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("stream_type")]
    public string StreamType { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("preview")]
    public StreamPreview Preview { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("channel")]
    public Channel channel { get; set; }


}
class StreamPreview
{
    [JsonProperty("small")]
    public string SmallPreview { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("medium")]
    public string MediumPreview { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("large")]
    public string LargPreview { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("template")]
    public string TemplatePreview { get; set; }
}


public class Channel
{
    [JsonProperty("mature")]
    public bool Mature { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("broadcaster_language")]
    public string BroadcasterLanguage { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("display_name")]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("game")]
    public string Game { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("language")]
    public string Language { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("_id")]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("created_at")]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("updated_at")]
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("partner")]
    public bool Partner { get; set; }             
    [JsonProperty("logo")]
    public string Logo { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("video_banner")]
    public string VideoBanner { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("profile_banner")]
    public string ProfileBanner { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("profile_banner_background_color")]
    public string ProfileBannerBackgroundColor { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("url")]
    public string Url { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("views")]
    public long Views { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("followers")]
    public long Followers { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("broadcaster_type")]
    public string BroadcastType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("stream_key")]
    public string StreamKey { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code that actually performs the deserialization?

Comment: think about using Newtonssoft library:
dynamic serializer = JObject.Parse(response);
var substream = new SubStream();
substream.Id = serializer.stream.id;
....

Comment: Oh sorry the deserialization comes from the RestSharp http://restsharp.org/

Comment: Okay sorry bros. I found my misstake just a simple misstype in the namespace of the class :/ looks like its time to sleep -.-

Answer (score 0):

1) use JSON Utils (https://jsonutils.com/) to generate your C# classes (for attributes select JsonProperty)

2) Newtonsoft.Json is pretty much the standard best library to work with JSON formats in .NET, you can get it from nuget.

3) The code should look something like this, and deserialization should work without any problems:

```
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonDef>(json);

            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    public class Preview
    {

        [JsonProperty("small")]
        public string small { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("medium")]
        public string medium { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("large")]
        public string large { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("template")]
        public string template { get; set; }
    }

    public class Channel
    {

        [JsonProperty("mature")]
        public bool mature { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("status")]
        public string status { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("broadcaster_language")]
        public string broadcaster_language { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("display_name")]
        public string display_name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("game")]
        public string game { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("language")]
        public string language { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("_id")]
        public int _id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("created_at")]
        public DateTime created_at { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("updated_at")]
        public DateTime updated_at { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("partner")]
        public bool partner { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("logo")]
        public string logo { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("video_banner")]
        public string video_banner { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("profile_banner")]
        public string profile_banner { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("profile_banner_background_color")]
        public string profile_banner_background_color { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("url")]
        public string url { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("views")]
        public int views { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("followers")]
        public int followers { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("broadcaster_type")]
        public string broadcaster_type { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("description")]
        public string description { get; set; }
    }

    public class Stream
    {

        [JsonProperty("_id")]
        public long _id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("game")]
        public string game { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("broadcast_platform")]
        public string broadcast_platform { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("community_id")]
        public string community_id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("community_ids")]
        public IList<string> community_ids { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("viewers")]
        public int viewers { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("video_height")]
        public int video_height { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("average_fps")]
        public double average_fps { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("delay")]
        public int delay { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("created_at")]
        public DateTime created_at { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("is_playlist")]
        public bool is_playlist { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("stream_type")]
        public string stream_type { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("preview")]
        public Preview preview { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("channel")]
        public Channel channel { get; set; }
    }

    public class JsonDef
    {

        [JsonProperty("stream")]
        public Stream stream { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the `DateTime` format of the JSON. It is not in a well-formed .Net `DateTime`. so you can get it as a string and then convert it the way you want or change its format into a readable .Net one.